# Triggering a WhatsApp intent by clicking a browser link

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, web-applications, whatsapp

I'm using Chrome to trigger [intents](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents) by clicking on links in the browser:

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=
                        com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

Works great with the barcode scanner. But is there any way to share an image in the same way for the WhatsApp application?

My guess it that it would look something like this (obviously missing the image here):

```
intent://send/#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;
                                            action=android.intent.action.SEND;end
```

But this only opens up the Google Play store and shows me WhatsApp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you only need to use this.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<<HERE GOES THE URL ENCODED TEXT YOU WANT TO SHARE>>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```